# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number : Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

can some one help me. I have this error when I try to login a admin.

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: select `users`.`firstname`, `users`.`lastname`, `clients`.`id` as `client_id` from `clients` inner join `users` on `clients`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` inner join `jobs` on `clients`.`id` = `jobs`.`client_id` where `clients`.`id` = 1 and `jobs`.`id` = ? limit 1)

```
public function getSelectedClient($id)
{
    return $this
        ->model
        ->join('users', 'clients.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('jobs','clients.id','=','jobs.client_id')
        ->select('users.firstname','users.lastname', 'clients.id as client_id')
        ->where('clients.id', $id)
        ->where('jobs.id',1)
        ->first();
}
```

Can someone help me why i am experiencing this error. thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you going to set a filter where `jobs.id=1` ?

Comment: Please upload a minimal-project that reproduces your issue. Did you replace the logic with "`->where('jobs.id',1)`" while posting the question?